# gridview with tab bar in android

Tags: android, layout, gridview, include, tabbar

I have to develop one android application.

Here i have to develop grid view layout like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/Layout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="Mercuryminds Shoppingcart Application"

    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:gravity="center" />

<GridView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"

    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp">
</GridView>

 <include        
 android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/footer" />


   </LinearLayout>
```

Here the layout footer is tab bar.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <TabHost
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TabWidget
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/tabs">
    </TabWidget>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
```

But i have to run the app means the tab bar is not display on my main view.whats wrong in my layout file.please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `layout_weight="1"` to your gridView and `layout_height="0dp"`

like this

```
  <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>
```

Comment: thanks.tabbar is displayed.how can i write the tab bar code on android:http://pastie.org/5609547

Comment: if i answered your question , you mush mark it as checked . for the second thing you can post a new question